# What is the meaning of $1^\lor=\delta$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, schwartz-space

I tried to look up the definition of a $\lor$ and it does not seem to explain this particular usage

$$1^\lor=\delta$$

This is used in a proof that inverse fourier transform of $1$ is $\delta$, but i have no idea what the above usage of notation implies.

Thanks

Comment: Note also that it depends on how you defined the fourier transform. If you have defined it as $\int _\mathbb R e^{-ixt}u(x) dx$, then $1^\vee = 2\pi \delta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check accent is often used to indicate the inverse Fourier transform. Since the difference between direct and inverse transform is a sign, it is a question of taste if this notation is needed.
$$
\check{\hat\phi}=\hat{\check\phi}=\phi
$$

Answer (score 1):

Given a distribution $D$, we use $\hat D$ to denote the Fourier transform, 
$$ \left< \hat D, \varphi \right> = \left< D, \hat \varphi \right>$$ 
Where $\hat \varphi$ is the classical Fourier transform on Schwartz space.

We can define ${\varphi}^{\vee}$ as, 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(-x) e^{-i\omega x} ~ dx $$
So this is like a transform but with a negative.

So I am guessing $D^{\vee}$ is defined just like for Fourier transform.

It does explain why $1^{\vee} = \delta$.

Comment: So the usage of $\lor$ is restricted to talking about the dirac delta function?

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant, no, it is well-defined for all tempered distributions.

Comment: Note that the integral is equal to $\int_{\mathbb R}\phi(x)e^{iωx} dx$, the formula for the inverse Fourier transform.